# How to massive update?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have three tables:

```
group:
  id - primary key
  name - varchar

profile:
    id - primary key
    name - varchar
    surname - varchar
    [...etc...]

profile_group:
    profile_id - integer, foreign key to table profile
    group_id - integer, foreign key to table group
```

Profiles may be in many groups. I have group named "Users" with id=1 and I want to assign all users to this group but only if there was no such entry for the table profiles.

How to do it?

Comment: Could you reword the question and be a bit more clear?  You have profiles and groups and want to assign all users to a group...is a profile a user then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you want to add entries like (*profile_id*, 1) into `profile_group` table for all profiles, that were not in this table before. If so, try this:

```
INSERT INTO profile_group(profile_id, group_id) 
     SELECT id, 1 FROM profile p 
     LEFT JOIN profile_group pg on (p.id=pg.profile_id) 
     WHERE pg.group_id IS NULL;
```

Comment: the issue with this answer is that the left join is not going to constrain to only profile_group records for group 1, take a look at the other answer on this question to see the correct implementation.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is use a left join to the profile group table and then exclude any matching records (this is done in the where clause of the below SQL statement).

This is faster than using `not in (select xxx)` since the query profiler seems to handle it better (in my experience)

```
insert into profile_group (profile_id, group_id)
select p.id, 1
from profiles p
left join profile_group pg on p.id = pg.profile_id 
    and pg.group_id = 1
where pg.profile_id is null
```